# C++/Eigen - How to pass a general vector as parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

Using Eigen 3.4.0

I want to write a function general for any Eigen::Vector. e.g.

Eigen provides MatrixBase for any Eigen object, but I want to be explicit that this is a vector only function.

For example, I could write a general MatrixBase function as follows:

```
   template<Derived>
   typename MatrixBase<Derived>::PlainObject foo(MatrixBase<Derived>& M)
   { // N = operations on M
     // ...
     return N;
   }
```

I want something to the effect of:

```
   template<Derived>
   typename VectorBase<Derived>::PlainObject foo(VectorBase<Derived>& M);
```

I tried:

```
  template<Derived>
   Vector<typename Derived::Scalar, Dynamic> foo(Vector<typename Derived::Scalar>& M);
```

This doesn't work.

My current solution is to just template the function and make the template clear to use vectors only, but doesn't seem like the best practice.

```
   template<VectorX>
   VectorX foo(VectorX M);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `VectorBase` in the Eigen library. `Eigen::Vector` is just an alias for `Eigen::Matrix`:

```
template<typename Type , int Size>
using   Eigen::Vector = Matrix< Type, Size, 1 >
```

So, if you want your function to allow only `Eigen::Vector`, then simply take a `Eigen::Vector` function argument, but you will need template arguments to match `Vector`'s template arguments, eg:

```
template<typename Type, int Size>
typename Eigen::Vector<Type,Size>::PlainObject foo(Eigen::Vector<Type,Size>& M);
```

Comment: Is that any better than just doing a `template<Vector>`?

Comment: Yes, because `template<Vector>` will allow any type (or at least, any type with a nested `PlainObject` type, in this example), whereas using `Eigen::Vector` directly is more specialized and will only allow `Eigen::Vector` types, which is what you asked for.

Comment: This approach risks performance degradations because it defeats the ability to take vector expressions as arguments, even just sub-vectors. I suggest at least switching to `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector>`

Comment: I'm avoiding using `Eigen::Ref` since I want Vectors of any type. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that the type system cannot differentiate between vectors and matrices in the parameter declaration. Eigen solves this by using [a set of macros](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicAssertions.html) that cause compile errors if you try it anyway. I suggest using the same approach:

```cpp
template<DerivedVector>
typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::PlainObject
foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedVector>& M)
{ 
    EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_ONLY(DerivedVector);
    return N;
}
```

If you want more control, you can always write your own static assertions, especially now with C++11 when this has become much simpler.

```cpp
template<class Derived>
inline constexpr bool isRowVector(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&)
{ return Derived::RowsAtCompileTime == 1; }

template<class Derived>
inline constexpr bool isColVector(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&)
{ return Derived::ColsAtCompileTime == 1; }

template<class Derived>
inline constexpr bool isVector(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& vec)
{ return isRowVector(vec) || isColVector(vec); }

template<DerivedVector>
typename Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedVector>::PlainObject
foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedVector>& M)
{ 
    static_assert(isVector(M));
    return N;
}
```